# Should titles of people be translated?

Tags: meaning, translation

Should titles of persons like (Mr., Herr, Sr...) be translated into English?

For example:
Herr Albert or Mr. Albert ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's really no *should* about it. This is entirely a matter of personal (or corporate) style, and context.

Comment: "Context" - you took the word right out of my mouth!

Comment: @J.R. It is always relevant.

Comment: I'm not so sure. There are legalities attached to some apparently innocuous issues when it comes to modes of address and labelling in general, and courts would argue that one _should_ follow the legal guidelines rather than any in-house or personal policy. For instance, legal action was taken against a person writing _Biro_ without the capital. There are possibly titles the dropping or substituting of which would be considered unlawful in certain countries, and international law sometimes overrules national law.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth: That's why I was careful to mention context.

Comment: The demands of context may negate your opening statement.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth. True.